# Duplicate 'Column' attribute

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am creating an entity using Entity Framework 4.1 and I am using column to give different names to columns. I have a composite key as well as foreign key but I am getting error

```
 public class Account
    {
 [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Account"), Column(Order = 0)]
        [Column("Creditor ID", Order = 0)]    //PK FK
        public int CreditorId { get; set; }


        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Account"), Column(Order = 1)]
        [Column("[Account No]", Order = 1)]            //PK FK
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
}
```

Both are primary key as well as foreign keys

I get following error:

**Duplicate 'Column' attribute**

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do! each property has two ColumnArtribute instances defined. The fact that they are on different lines and in different sets of square brackets is irrelevant.

It looks like in both cases the one on the first line is redundant.

Comment: [ForeignKey("Account"), Column(Order = 1)] In this line I have used column to show that it matched with account entity's first column and  [Column("Account No", Order=1)]  shows that it is part of primary key and its order is 0

Comment: @Dotnet - there is no association between them just because of the layout; that is identical to `[ForeignKey("Account")] [Column(Order = 1)]  [Column("Account No", Order=1)]`, or `[ForeignKey("Account"), Column(Order = 1), Column("Account No", Order=1)]`. Honestly, try removing the Column(...) from the first line.